# How to read a message from Azure Dead Letter Queue using MassTransit

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, dead-letter

I'm trying to find a code to read a message from Azure dead letter queue using MassTransit and print it in the console. Looking for the right class and method to do the job.

Comment: Have you tried to change the queue name to below in this code : https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/azure-sb.html

<queue path>/$deadletterqueue or <topic path>/Subscriptions/<subscription path>/$deadletterqueue

Answer (score 0):

Changing the queue name to below in [this code](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/azure-sb.html) should help you.

Reading from Deadletter queue : yourqueuename/$deadletterqueue

Reading from Deadletter topic subscription : yourtopicname/Subscriptions/yoursubscriptionname/$deadletterqueue